# potatoes counting 4 letter words permutation

Tags: combinatorics

George is making a list of all 606 four-letter permutations of the word “POTATOES”. He then arranges the “words” in alphabetical order. Which position  is “AOPS” in? For example, the word “AEOO” is in position 1.

I got -

AE** OO OP OS OT PO PS PT SO SP ST TO TT TP TS - 14
AOE* O P S T - 4
AOO* E P S T 4
AOP* E O -2

so there are 24 in front of AOPS, and answer should be 25. But the provided answer is 26. What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: Your work looks correct to me.  As far as counting arrangements beginning with AE:  There are two ways to complete the word with a double letter (OO or TT), and there are $4 \cdot 3$ ways to complete the word by arranging two different letters chosen from the set $\{O, P, S, T\}$, giving a total of $2 + 12 = 14$ words, as you found.

Comment: As a double check, a short program in Python confirms that the answer is 25.